# Control AC load with microcontroller. TRIAC behaviour problem

Tags: microcontroller, triac

As per the title of this question i'm trying to control an ac resistive load. So far i had little success and i'm experiencing "strange", to me at least, behaviour from the triac(s) i tried. first of all i post a schematic of my test circuit (bare with it, it's not a complete schematic, it represents only the control part)
[image: digidimmer.png]

as you can see it's sized for a 220v ac line
missing in the schematic is a quadrature encoder input used to control the delay of the firing pulse to the opto.
What i did is take the zero cross signal and compute a delay based on the encoder input (ie if the input was 5 out of 10 i'd start a timer on ZCD and once it reaches 5 it would trigger the opto led thus triggering the BTA10 triac)
So far so good, the ZCD outputs a nice spike which is read by the pic and the output to the MOC is perfectly timed. Now comes the problems. Just to test the circuit i tried first with 15vAC (sizing the resistors accordingly and using a couple of car tail lights as a load) and i experienced this problem
[image: Name: AREA.png Views: 4 Size: 4.2 KB]

ok, i don't draw very well...what was happening was that the triac switched nicely in the green region and won't turn on at all in the red one. i was puzzled but i thought it could be a voltage problem so i went from 15v to 110vAC (again changing the resistors and load). Now the triac switched on only at the very beginning of each half wave right after ZC. Sometimes switching only one half of the full wave. As soon as i delay my triggering signal more than a few hundreds uS or so the triac just stops working. I also changed the load to a beefier one (a heater) to increase current but nothing happened. I also tried playing with the resistors a bit to see if i can get some changes but had no luck. Now reading some forums I thought I may get rid of the transformer i used to supply my circuit with 15vAC first and 110vAC after and connect everything directly to the mains as it will eventually be. But maybe someone can point me directly to the correct answer! May the transformer be the culprit? If not what can it be?
I don't have much experience with TRIACS so my knowledge is surely lacking something and i may have forgot something important in the description of what I'm doing that can be helpful to get the answer right...
Just to be sure i link here the datasheets of the triac, optocoupler and optotriac. And an app note with some of the calculations i've used.

www.vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf

www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MO/MOC3023M.pdf

www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-3003.pdf

www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00004894.pdf?s_searchtype=keyword

Comment: Have you measured the LED current (eg. by looking at the voltage across the 150 ohm resistor)? It looks marginal.

Comment: @Spehro If he's using the opto part he says it'll work at 5mA from the PIC

Comment: Data sheet says 30mA, but I would not be surprised if they all meet the most sensitive spec. Kind of a long shot.

Comment: How long is the pulse that activates the opto triac?

Comment: Is your PIC resetting as soon as it fires?

Comment: Tomorrow evening i'll measure the led current but i guess 20/25mA (maximum allowed by PIC output) should be enough or i don't understand why the TRIAC fires correctly towards zero and not at wave peaks, at 15vAC, and only at the beginning of each half wave @110vAC. Nevertheless i'll try adding a transistor buffer!

Comment: Pulse length. I begun with some 10's of uS, then went up to the 100's and finally tried with milliseconds long pulse. No change whatsoever. As for the pic resetting after triac firing i have no clues to suspect that, the timing is spot on and long pulses lasts as long as they should...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sorry for the late reply, i had access to my bench only today. As you suggested i put a transitor to drive the opto and went up to 50mA but no change in behaviour

Comment: @Andyaka i added a "reset catch" routine to see if there was any problem (actually a led that lights up at the beginning of the program, before the main loop) and noticed no problems...i'm clueless :(

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure the optocoupler is the part number you say it is? There are similar type numbers that are "zero voltage switching" and I would say it's within the realm of possibility that they could be found in the same bag, even from a normally reliable distributor.

Comment: i didn't check before and put it on blindly, turns out it's a moc3020 with NO "M" at the end. Don't know if it's just a revision or a component with completely different functionality. Thanks for the heads up, i'll try to see if it's a different component or not or just try with an actual 3020M

Comment: Hey there, @zakkos, did you finish the project?

Comment: @Vorac indeed I did. Sorry for the late reply, hope you see this. I sort of got around the problem, even benefit from it. What I was controlling was a heating element so speed was not an issue. If it would have been lights then i would have been screwed. I wrote a soft PWM with a period of 1 second, I just used the zero cross part of my circuit to issue an interrupt that added a tick to a counter. The frequency of the mains is well known and quite stable so you know that after 100 ticks a second has elapsed. This came very handy as I could use that as a base for a percentile PWM without remap

Comment: Since the triac had no problems around the ZC it was just about too happy to comply with my request of firing at some microseconds after a ZC was detected (provided that the right amount of ticks had elapsed and all the other control stuffs matched). The added benefit (huge benefit actually) was that by firing at (or near) ZC I avoided many many problems with EMI interferences, something that haunted another project where a similar 2KW heating element was involved but switched with a relay that wreaked havoc with the logic. Luckily this experience had taught me a lot. Good luck @Vorac

Answer (score 1):

You could try building an ZCD circuit using Transistor. CE configuration. You need to size your AC input voltage to something reasonable using Voltage Divider.

[image]

Choose the voltage divider resistors and keep in mind the power dissipation too. Mostly 1/4W resistors will be sufficient.

Triggering Quadrant of Triac

Answer (score 0):

The idea and the circuit works well, including the zero crossing. But consider the followings:

- your zero crossing works in one halfcycle only. It is rather a "positive voltage checking" than a zero crossing circuit, so you need to consider that you need to fire the triac e.g. 5ms after L->H and 5 ms after H->L transitions as well. I found adding a simple bridge rectifier can eliminate this hassle.
- consider changing R3 to 220-470 ohm, you're firing (sorry for the pun) the LED in the optotriac
- consider making wider trigger pulses. I.e. a trigger pulse is not just a pulse of say, 500uS. Feel free to make it as wide as necessary, usually 1-2ms.