# Controlling AC load from a microcontroller GPIO with triac

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I have the above question and I don't know who to ask. I looked around here, while most have no answers but there are a couple that kind of applies but went a little over my head, like these:

1. [Directly controlling an AC load with a power phototriac](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304450/directly-controlling-an-ac-load-with-a-power-phototriac)
2. [Control AC load with microcontroller. TRIAC behaviour problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98698/control-ac-load-with-microcontroller-triac-behaviour-problem)

I am trying to control various AC loads (240V, 1000W) with a microcontroller GPIO pin.

I found [this](https://components101.com/ics/moc3021-triac-driven-optoisolator-pinout-equivalent-datasheet) tutorial online and I want to just follow it.

But I don't know how to find the right components, provided the circuit works.

(1) For U1, I want to use MOC3021 optoisolator, will that be OK?
(2) For U2, I want to use BT134-600 triac (600V, 4A), will that be OK?
(3) How do I size R1 and R2, can I use just those same values?

I apologise in advance if this question is too simple/stupid. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(1) For U1, I want to use MOC3021 optoisolator, will that be OK?*

Yes.

*(2) For U2, I want to use BT134-600 triac (600V, 4A), will that be OK?*

If your AC loads will be 240 V, 1000 W, a 4A triac is "just enough", and this is not adviseable. Choose a 8A x 800 V triac, the price difference is minimal.

Be careful with 240 AC mains.

*(3) How do I size R1 and R2, can I use just those same values?*

These values are not critical. But make sure that your uC output pin can supply the MOC3021's *trigger current* (edited), and that the load resistor R1 don't reduce this current. Maybe it will be necessary change the load resistor, or add a transistor.

Check the sensitivity data of the 8A triac, maybe you will need to change R2 value (most probably 1k will be OK, but this should be checked).

Comment: Thank you very much. That is very helpful. 
I didn't know 8A triacs are available, I got lucky while scrolling and found the 4A triac. I now have found some 8A options thanks to you.

Thanks for the rest of the tip. But I need one more help, what do you mean sensitivity data of the triac that influences the R2 value? Is there a tutorial that can help explain this part?

Comment: Also be careful with heatsinking the triac. You're likely to need it.

Comment: "sensitivity" is the name used in Triac's datasheets for the minimum current needed to trigger the triac on. There are low sensitivity triacs that needs currents about 50mA, there are high sensibility triacs that trigger with lower currents. The regular ones needs about 25 mA, that can be provided by 1K resistor @ 240 V. But if you get a "low sensitivity" triac, maybe you will need a lower resistor.